# loop through new.env() R (quantmod)

Tags: r, loops, quantmod

I am new to R, loop and quantmod.
I am trying to build a database that can be used be used easier for calculations (in a column format).

I was wondering how you would use a "loop" to automate the process below.
I am simply binding two datasets together.

As you can see, I have bound two datasets together using rbind, Google and Apple stock prices. If I was to have 100 stocks, this process would take a very long time, thus I was wondering how I could automate this process?

```
library(quantmod)
tickers<- c("AAPL", "GOOG")
all<- new.env()
getSymbols(tickers,src="google", env = all, from = Sys.Date()-100, to = Sys.Date())

apple_share<- all$AAPL
colnames(apple_share)<- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume")
apple_share$Ticker<- rep(1, nrow(apple_share))

google_share<- all$GOOG
colnames(google_share)<- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume")
google_share$Ticker<- rep(2, nrow(google_share))

combined_data<- rbind(apple_share,google_share)
```

Many thanks,

Shoups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `tidyquant` was created exactly for tasks like the one you asked for. Assuming that you updated the `quantmod` package to version 0.4-9, which again allows price downloads from YAHOO, the `tq_get` function will download the data and with "grouping by symbol” you will get the desired output.

```
> library(tidyquant)
stocks <- c("AAPL", "GOOG", "NFLX") %>%
     tq_get(get  = "stock.prices",
            from = "2010-01-01",
            to   = "2015-12-31") %>%
     group_by(symbol)

> stocks
Source: local data frame [4,527 x 8]
Groups: symbol [3]

# A tibble: 4,527 x 8
   symbol       date   open   high    low  close    volume
    <chr>     <date>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
 1   AAPL 2010-01-04 213.43 214.50 212.38 214.01 123432400
 2   AAPL 2010-01-05 214.60 215.59 213.25 214.38 150476200
 3   AAPL 2010-01-06 214.38 215.23 210.75 210.97 138040000
 4   AAPL 2010-01-07 211.75 212.00 209.05 210.58 119282800
 5   AAPL 2010-01-08 210.30 212.00 209.06 211.98 111902700
 6   AAPL 2010-01-11 212.80 213.00 208.45 210.11 115557400
 7   AAPL 2010-01-12 209.19 209.77 206.42 207.72 148614900
 8   AAPL 2010-01-13 207.87 210.93 204.10 210.65 151473000
 9   AAPL 2010-01-14 210.11 210.46 209.02 209.43 108223500
10   AAPL 2010-01-15 210.93 211.60 205.87 205.93 148516900
# ... with 4,517 more rows, and 1 more variables: adjusted <dbl>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get the values using `mget`

```
lst <- Map(cbind, mget(tickers, envir = all), Ticker = seq_along(tickers))
lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) setNames(x, sub("[^.]+\\.", "", names(x))))
newdat <- do.call(rbind, lst)
head(newdat)
#             Open   High    Low  Close   Volume Ticker
#2017-02-23 137.38 137.48 136.30 136.53 20788186      1
#2017-02-23 830.12 832.46 822.88 831.33  1472771      2
#2017-02-24 135.91 136.66 135.28 136.66 21776585      1
#2017-02-24 827.73 829.00 824.20 828.64  1392202      2
#2017-02-27 137.14 137.44 136.28 136.93 20257426      1
#2017-02-27 824.55 830.50 824.00 829.28  1101466      2
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
That was really helpful. I will look into this with more detail :)

Comment: Hi, Sorry to bother you again. Thanks again for the code. There is a part I am slightly confused about. You wrote: setNames(x, sub("[^.]+\\.", "", names(x)), I assume this was a function you made to substitute the heading of the columns so it only shows "Open" rather than "AAPL.Open". I was wondering what the [^.]+\\ stood for? I have never seen that before.

Comment: @ShuopengCui  It is based on your code to replace the prefix with 'AAPL.Open' to 'Open'.   The syntax `[^.]+` is to match one or more character that are not a `.`